# How to write PMPI library for wrapping MPI functions

Tags: c++, mpi, libraries

I am trying to write a PMPI library but am not sure of the right steps (new to libraries and linking). I have written a basic file wrapping the MPI_Send function. Say it's a file called lib.c, what all  steps should I do so that when I run a c code with MPI_Send, my wrapper code gets executed?

Answer (score 1):

On Linux, MPI uses weak links so that MPI_Send gets redirected to PMPI calls. So if you link with your library first and then the MPI library that you are wrapping (i.e. `-lmpi` is after `-lmylib`), you will be calling MPI through your library, because then libmpi weak links won't be used.

Comment: How do I "link" the library. Also how do I go from the c code to the library. I tried a few times things, but none worked for me.

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand the comment. `-lmylib -lmpi` works if you are implementing the `MPI_` calls in C. If you need a more precise answer, please provide a more precise question with what doesn't work and what you tried.