# How to write MPI library for profiling

Tags: c, shared-libraries, mpi, dynamic-linking

I want to, say, write a string before all MPI_Sends called in a program written in C. For this, I want to write a profiling library. I wrote this code in mylib.c

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <mpi.h>

int MPI_Send(void *buf, int count, MPI_Datatype type, int to, int tag, MPI_Comm comm)
{
    printf("Some string");
    return PMPI_Send(buf, count, type, to, tag, comm);
}
```

If I run `mpicc -fPIC mylib.c -o mylib.o` I get the error- `error: conflicting types for ‘MPI_Send’`
How do I write this code correctly and how do I compile and link this to my mpi program?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to write PMPI library for wrapping MPI functions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55118661/how-to-write-pmpi-library-for-wrapping-mpi-functions)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to declare your function with this signature:

```
int MPI_Send(const void* buf, int count, MPI_Datatype type, 
             int to, int tag, MPI_Comm comm) { ... }
```

The first parameter is `const`. `void* != const void*`.  That's what you're missing.  Check here for example: https://www.mpich.org/static/docs/latest/www3/MPI_Send.html